# Error in installing "hadley/bigvis"

Tags: r, github

```
find_rtools()

[1] TRUE

Sys.which( "g++" )
g++ 
"C:\\PROGRA~1\\MINGW-~1\\X86_64~1.2-P\\mingw64\\bin\\G__~1.EXE" \
devtools::install_github("hadley/bigvis")\

Downloading github repo hadley/bigvis@master\
Installing bigvis

"F:/PROGRA~1/R-31~1.2/bin/x64/R" --vanilla CMD INSTALL  

  "C:/Users/Qiuyang/AppData/Local/Temp/Rtmp2JMGDL/devtools33f847ad29a4/hadley-bigvis-1cdfdc2"  

  --library="F:/Program files/R-3.1.2/library" --install-tests 

    (omit some lines)

make: *** [group.o] Error 1

Warning: running command 'make -f "Makevars.win" -f "F:/PROGRA~1/R-31~1.2/etc/x64/Makeconf" -f "F:/PROGRA~1/R-31~1.2/share/make/winshlib.mk" SHLIB_LDFLAGS='$(SHLIB_CXXLDFLAGS)' SHLIB_LD='$(SHLIB_CXXLD)' SHLIB="bigvis.dll" WIN=64 TCLBIN=64 OBJECTS="BigVis.o BinnedVector.o BinnedVectors.o RcppExports.o Summary2d.o condense.o double-diff-sum.o frange.o group.o lowerBound.o smooth-nd.o stats.o summary.o"' had status 2

ERROR: compilation failed for package 'bigvis'

* removing 'F:/Program files/R-3.1.2/library/bigvis'

Error: Command failed (1)

install.packages("bigvis-master", repos = NULL, type = "source")

Warning: invalid package 'bigvis-master'

Error: ERROR: no packages specified

Warning messages:

1: running command '"F:/PROGRA~1/R-31~1.2/bin/x64/R" CMD INSTALL -l "F:\Program files\R-3.1.2\library" "bigvis-master"' had status 1 

2: In install.packages("bigvis-master", repos = NULL, type = "source") :
  installation of package ‘bigvis-master’ had non-zero exit status
```

There is link to previous answers. However neither work for me.

[Is the bigvis package for R not available for R version 3.0.1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18151988/is-the-bigvis-package-for-r-not-available-for-r-version-3-0-1/24765223#24765223)

Answer (score 2):

I had exactly the same problem and I think it's an incompatibility with the latest version of Rcpp. For me, bigvis installed when I used Rcpp 0.11.3, which is available from

http://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/Rcpp/

You need to copy the zip file and install from source.

Hope it works for you too.

Comment: good. At least you gave me a reasonable explaination. :) But now I have trouble installing rcpp 0.11.3.

Comment: These are the commands I used:
library(installr)
install.Rtools()

remove.packages("Rcpp")

#  edit the path in the next line to tell it where you 
# saved Rcpp_0.11.3.tar.gz
install.packages("Rcpp_0.11.3.tar.gz", repos = NULL, type = "source")

devtools::install_github("hadley/bigvis")

Comment: install.packages("Rcpp_0.11.3.tar.gz",repos=NULL,type="source") 
(omit)
make: *** [Date.o] Error 1
Warning: running command 'make -f "Makevars.win" (omit...) has status 2.

Comment: Do you have Rtools in your path?

Comment: > library("devtools")
> find_rtools()
[1] TRUE

Answer (score 2):

I ran into a similar problem today and, given what ended up working for me, double check that you are using [RTools 3.1](http://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/) as well as [Rcpp 0.11.3](http://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/Rcpp/).

In the case of Rcpp, I installed the latest version and then downloaded 0.11.3 from the link above. Without bothering to remove the latest version, I simply entered the following command:

```
install.packages("Rcpp_0.11.3.tar.gz", repos = NULL, type = "source")
```

Once I had both RTools 3.1 and Rcpp 0.11.3, `devtools::install_github('hadley/bigvis')` worked without issue.

Hope this helps.